# How to increase AWS EC2 instance CPU utilization to 100% to test autoscaling group creating new instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I need to test autoscaling group creating new instances when CPU utilization cross certain threshold for example 70%.

Is there any way to up the CPU utilization just to test?

Comment: Run scripts like these: https://gist.github.com/tott/3895832

Comment: All joking aside: run a bitcoin miner.

Comment: You might get more a specific / refined / controllable suggestion on ServerFault.

Comment: Windows (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2012/10/26/tools-to-simulate-cpu-memory-disk-load/) or Linux (https://superuser.com/questions/443406/how-can-i-produce-high-cpu-load-on-a-linux-server).

Comment: Do you want to test the Auto Scaling Group functionality or the instance it lunches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are testing a web based application, I recommend you try [Bees With Machine Guns](https://github.com/newsapps/beeswithmachineguns).

Its a python script that will launch micro EC2 instances and send many web requests from these instances to your application. This will simulate a large surge in traffic for performance testing.

Note the caveat at the bottom of the page that says:

> If you decide to use the Bees, please keep in mind the following important caveat: they are, more-or-less a distributed denial-of-service attack in a fancy package and, therefore, if you point them at any server you don’t own you will behaving unethically, have your Amazon Web Services account locked-out, and be liable in a court of law for any downtime you cause.
>
> You have been warned.

Answer (score 4):

You can use stress command in **Linux**:

```
stress --cpu 2 --timeout 60
```

cpu specifies the number of cores, timeout specifies the number of seconds this command will run.

For **Windows**:
Install [Windows Server 2003 Resource Toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17657).
Then run this command in cmd:

```
consume -cpu-time -time 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to bring CPU utilization up on Posix systems is to use the [stress](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/) command.  Stress generates CPU, memory, I/O or disk workload depending on your configuration.

An example [answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99435/200062) shows how to use stress to bring the memory of an instance to 90%.

Answer (score 0):

just run a dummy shell script on putty instance

```
while true;do echo;done
```